# Apache POI 3.7 Renumbering Rows

Tags: apache-poi

Hello wonderful Stackoverflow people. 
I have created a spreadshhet with Apache Poi 3.7. The first two rows of the spreadsheet display header information. Then starting at line 3 returned data is populated on the spreadsheet. My question is there a way to start the row numbering at row 3. Such as, I want row three of the spreadshhet to state '1' not '3'.

1 Date Processed:   07/30/2013 13:39
2 ACNT_TMSTP             IMPL_STAT_CD
3 07/30/2013 12:23        L

Comment: Can you do whatever you want in Excel application. I don't think you can do it. As per my knowledge its not possible. Well, you can do this by adding `row= row+2 ` only.

Comment: If it's not really part of the tabled data, might I suggest adding it as a header?  [`sheet.getHeader()`](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet.html#getHeader()) will return a [Header](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Header.html) object where you can set the content.  Unfortunately, I think that'll force you into page layout view (in Excel)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Headers only are displayed only on hardcopys(print outs). If a header is wanted to be displayed like for column titles then they will need to be created at the top of the spreadsheet in the rows. A freezpane can be added to freeze these headings/titles for scrolling purposes.